# CMD hangs when I create a react project using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cmd, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new react project but CMD hanged at some point. Do I need to install something?

[image: Creating A new Project]

Comment: try to add `--verbose` at the end of the line, it might give you a hint on what is happening...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I removed the file and re start cmd and then create a new setup and it works. Thats odd but its working fine now

Comment: file conflict probably....